# Indent text in list items with images and list-style-type set to none

Tags: css, text, alignment

My problem is kind of similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963735/indent-list-items-with-floating-image-problem), but I have `img` within `li`s of my unordered list.

Following is my markup. (think of it as UI for comments, as in Facebook or G+, where comment text and user's profile picture thumbnail is shown side-by-side)

```
<ul class="comments">
    <li><img src="thumb.jpg" class="user-img" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
    <li><img src="thumb.jpg" class="user-img" />Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    <li><img src="thumb.jpg" class="user-img" />Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat. Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
    <li><img src="thumb.jpg" class="user-img" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
</ul>
```

And following is the CSS for the same.

```
.comments {
    list-style-type: none;
    clear: both;
}

.comments li {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.comments li img {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

And I'm getting result as following:

[image: Ugly List Text Indentation]

As it is clearly visible that when text doesn't fit the width, it goes below the image which I don't want. How can I keep it aligned instead of flowing below thumbnail image?

**Note:**

The images used for list items are not intended to be used as `list-style-image`, this is prototype design and images will be different for each `li`.

Comment: Are the thumbnail images same for all li?

Comment: @Dipaks: No, I'm working on prototype design, they'll be different for each `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the thumbnail images are different for each li use [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/taZnM/1/)

If the thumbnail images are same for all li. Do this -

```
.comments li {
    background: url(thumb.jpg) no-repeat left top;
    padding: 0 0 10px 50px;
    font-size: 12px; min-height: 44px; /*thumb image height*/
}
```

Comment: Fiddle was the exact solution I was looking for, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
.comments
{
list-style-image:url('thumb.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Yes use this approach. +1. You don't want the images to be inline markup. Use backgrounds or list styles.

Comment: I could use it, but image thumbnails are not used here as `list-style-image`.

Comment: @Dipaks your downvote is petty.  If its dynamically generated content, the CSS would be pretty much the same, just shifted to being inline.

Comment: @Baronth meaning more CSS Classes

Comment: @Baronth use miss SEO (alt/title attribute) if you call an image from CSS - read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492809/when-to-use-img-vs-css-background-image

Comment: @Dipaks actually using images with alt or title in this case is sure not SEO friendly; Remember that alts are showed on text browsers or browsers for blind people;  why the browser have to show an alt (or "tell" if blind people browser) to a list point image?